# Making Gmail the default mail app made sharing via Email disappear from Photos app?

Tags: mail.app, google-chrome, gmail, photos.app

I would like use the "Share" menu in Photos to share photos via email. This was by default bringing up the Mail app, but I don't use that and would prefer to have things simply open in Gmail in my browser (Chrome).

I was able to configure GMail as my default mail reader by letting GMail set itself up as the default mail handler in Chrome, and then going to Apple Mail and configuring the "Default email reader" to "Google Chrome", like this:

[image]

Great! I thought I was all set.  Unfortunately, when I try to use the "Share..." menu in Apple Photos, "Email" is no longer an option. It has simply disappeared:

[image]

Is there any way to get the "Email..." share option to show up when using Gmail (via Chrome) as my default mail reader?

Answer (score 1):

Correct.

Extensions in the Share menu are provided by the application.  You set something other than Mail.app as the email client, so the Share target disappeared.

I doubt the web browser is providing a Share extension.